# From an established ssh connection, what is a good way to encrypt messages on the side?

Tags: ssh, encryption

If I have a connection between a client and a server using ssh.  What is a good way to encrypt data sent outside the ssh connection for sending large amounts of data quickly and securely?  I can use the ssh connection to set up the terms of the communication, sharing keys etc, but then will do the communication on the side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick a random symmetric key on one side, send it to the other side over the ssh connection, then use that key to encrypt your side traffic.  A 128-bit AES key should work fine, encryption/decryption using AES is fast and secure.

You should pass a random initialization vector as well.  Doesn't need to be over ssh, but passing it together with the key is probably easiest.